# How to prove $\mathbb R/(\mathbb Z+\alpha \mathbb Z) \simeq \mathbb T^2/\Delta_\alpha$, the irrational torus, in diffeology?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions, diffeomorphism

I was reading [this introductory text](http://math.huji.ac.il/~piz/documents/AITD.pdf) on **diffeology** by Patrick Iglesias-Zemmour and it is claimed in page $18$ that $T_\alpha$ is diffeomorphic $\mathbb R/(\mathbb Z + \alpha \mathbb Z)$, where $\alpha$ is an irrational number. The space $T_\alpha$ is the irrational torus defined as $\mathbb T^2/\Delta_\alpha$, where $\Delta_\alpha$ is the dense subgroup $\{[x,\alpha x], x\in \mathbb R\}$, and $\mathbb T^2 = \mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$, the usual torus. So far I was able to prove the map 
$$\Lambda:T_\alpha \to \mathbb R/(\mathbb Z + \alpha \mathbb Z),
$$
 given by $\Lambda[x,y] = [y-\alpha x]$, is smooth (in the sense of diffeology) and bijective. Nevertheless, I don't have the inverse map explicitly and I have no idea how to verify this inverse is smooth. So, here is my question:

> How do I prove $\Lambda^{-1}$ is smooth?

Comment: For $a \in \Bbb{R-Q}$, $z\to \Re(z) - a^{-1}\Im(z)$ induces the group isomorphism $\Bbb{C/(Z+iZ+(1+ia)R)\to R/(Z+a^{-1} Z)}$, $z+H\to (z+H)\cap \Bbb{R}$ whose inverse is induced by $x\to x$.

Comment: I see. The inverse is $g[x] = [(0,x)]$. Indeed:
$$\Lambda\circ g[x] = \Lambda[(0,x)] = x,$$
$$ g \circ \Lambda[x,y] = g[y-ax] = [(0,y-ax)]=[(x,y)].$$
Thank you very much!